# C# Progress Bar Min value is not updating from textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, windows-forms-designer

Im trying to work with progress bar in C# WFA.
My code works but i have problem with Min value of progress bar. It only works when i enter max value first not min.
When i enter min value first it starts from 0 every time i dont know why.
Any ideas?

```
    private void textBoxWartosc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxWartosc.Text))
        {

        }
        else
        if ((Convert.ToInt32(textBoxWartosc.Text)) >= (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMin.Text)) && (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxWartosc.Text)) <= (Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text)))
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxWartosc.Text);
            progressBar1.Value = i;
        }
    }


    private void textBoxMax_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMax.Text);
        progressBar1.Maximum = i;
    }

    private void textBoxMin_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxMin.Text);
        progressBar1.Minimum = i;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's because the initial Value for `MinValue` and `MaxValue` is `0` in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's take a look at how the ProgressBar behaves. The main rule is that the minimum will always be **less than or equal to** the maximum. So if you change the value of maximum to something less than the minimum, you are changing the minimum too. clear?

So, I guess this is the case here: first you change the minimum to something lets say 120, you'll have:

```
minumum = 120 , maximum = 120    // maximum also changes from 100 to 120 based on the rule
```

then you try to input the maximum amount to let's say `180`, but the `TextChanged` event gets called three times. First, as soon as you insert the `"1"`, so you will have:

```
minimum = 1 , maximum = 1    // minimum also changes because 1 is less than 100
```

Second, when you enter `"8"`, now you will have:

```
minimum = 1 , maximum = 18   // now minimum stays 1
```

and then when you enter the final `"0"` and the final situation will be:

```
minimum = 1 , maximum = 180
```

There are lot's of ways to solve this, but I suggest

1: you use the `Leave` event instead of `TextChanged`

or 2: put a `Save` button there and change alter values only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thank you! Leave event really helped me :)